# How to change position of scrollbar +100 px from bottom of div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I created my code but I do not know how to acquire what title said

```
    var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');
    var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');
    var windowheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('clientHeight');

    if(scrolltop ==(scrollheight-windowheight)){
        loaddata(form_data , size);
    }
    else{

    }
```

with this script i will check if scroll reach to bottom of div or not if reached i will fire up loaddata function but the problem is when this fire ajax script if scroll reach to bottom many ajax call will happen.now i need to change the position of scrollbar to not allow this.

i did something like this until now,but no success unfortunately.

```
    $('#content').animate({scrollTop : 100}, "slow");
```

of curse i need to animate this scroll but nothing happen.

thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

the question is clear how to change scrollbar position by jquery?

Comment: Please post the code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score -1):

i found where the problem was..in jquery you can use scrollTop to go to the y axis area but you have to select right to div..in my case i had to scroll $('scrollbox') and not content div.problem solved